# Measuring short-term, long-term and sensory memory in adolescents?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, measurement

I would like to measure the short-term memory, long-term memory and sensory memory of children between 10 and 15. If possible, I would prefer a single test or battery.

**What tests are used to measure adolescents' short-term, long-term and sensory memory?**