# Neurotransmitter detection in the brain

Tags: neuroscience

How are the effects of drugs in the brain, in terms of neurotransmitters measured? For example, Selective Seretonin Reuptake Inhibitors are a class of anti-depressants. How was and is this type of information about hor neurotransmitters act obtained?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I mean what tools or techniques are used to measure these types of things? Like if a drug releases dopamine, it's not just a wild guess there must have been a way to come to that conclusion. To know which receptors it activates and all that.

Comment: I spent like 10min looking around on google and couldn't find anything. Then came here.

Comment: I'm not sure there are many drugs that "take up" or "activate" dopamine by the way.

Comment: I made a pretty big edit, let me know if it gets to the core of what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I am asking. You said it clearer that what I wrote. Like is this with some sort of scanning device or is it a Theory from cutting open the brain and looking at it with a microscope?

Comment: I remember to have read somewhere that they do the measurement from gut but not sure

Comment: I'd recommend this previous answer which, I think, answers most of your questions. Surprisingly, many drugs are discovered by accident and their mechanisms are often worked out in the lab, or in animals, rather than in vivo. http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/which-neurotransmitters-can-be-measured-in-a-living-human-brain?rq=1

Comment: look up "microdialysis"