# How does neurotransmitter distribution and usage vary thought the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request

I understand that neurotransmitters are used to send signals between neurons in the brain and that some are used for rather specific functions. However, is the exact distribution/concentration/consumption and tolerances of neurotransmitters in various areas of the brain known?

Related and considered: 
[Which neurotransmitters can be measured in a living human brain?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/which-neurotransmitters-can-be-measured-in-a-living-human-brain) 
[Neurotransmitter based imaging techniques](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/neurotransmitter-based-imaging-techniques)

Comment: The distribution of receptors (and their subtypes) is much more important than the concentrations of the neurotransmitters, which (despite science journalism's focus of late) are very dynamic.

Comment: @ChuckSherrington I think that comment could be developed into a worthwhile answer if you could give me some references. (: